# Is it possible to convert a variable as a string?

Tags: python

I have a list, that I wanted to convert to a dictionary.

```
  L =   [ 
       is_text, 
       is_archive, 
       is_hidden, 
       is_system_file, 
       is_xhtml, 
       is_audio, 
       is_video,
       is_unrecognised
     ]
```

Is there any way to do this, can I convert to dictionary like this by program:

```
{
    "is_text": is_text, 
    "is_archive": is_archive, 
    "is_hidden" :  is_hidden
    "is_system_file": is_system_file
    "is_xhtml": is_xhtml, 
    "is_audio": is_audio, 
    "is_video": is_video,
    "is_unrecognised": is_unrecognised
}
```

Variables are boolean here.

So that I can easily pass this dictionary to my function

```
def updateFileAttributes(self, file_attributes):
    m = models.FileAttributes(**file_attributes)
    m.save()
```

Comment: Variables are just references to objects, there's no way to print a variable's name.

Comment: You are not the first person to ask this. I found at least 3 duplicates (search string: _"python variable as string"_)

Comment: Why do you need to do this?

Comment: @Blender: I have updated my question, why I would need that, Please check!

Comment: The best way is to not have them as variables in the first place. Or make them attributes of some object.

Comment: Your whole models looks wrong -- instead of having a list of is_ fields of which only one is true, shouldn't you have a ChoiceField? Then instead of the dictionary, you'd just have a single variable that says what kind of type the file is recognized as.

Comment: Unless of course a file can have several is_x fields True.

Comment: I mean an IntegerField with a choices parameter, not a ChoiceField, of course. Models don't have ChoiceFields, forms do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't get the name of a variable after you put it into a list, but you can do:

```
In [211]: is_text = True

In [212]: d = dict(is_text=is_text)
Out[212]: {'is_text': True}
```

Note that the value stored in `d` are boolean constants once you create it, you cannot change the value of `d['is_text']` dynamically by changing variable `is_text` because a bool is immutable.

In your case, you don't have to make `file_attributes` a compound data structure, just make it a **keyword argument**:

```
def updateFileAttributes(self, **file_attributes):
    m = models.FileAttributes(**file_attributes)
    m.save()
```

then you can call the function this way:

```
yourObj.updateFileAttributes(is_text=True, ...)
```

Comment: I like `dict(is_text=is_text)` trick, it uses **kargv correct?

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan why not? sorry for not quite catching you ...

Answer (score 0):

I have made few assumptions here to derive this result.
The variables in the List are the only available bool variables in the scope.

```
{ x:eval(x) for x in dir() if type(eval(x)) is bool }
```

or if you have enforced an naming convention for your variables

```
{ x:eval(x) for x in  dir() if x.startswith('is_') }
```

Answer (score -1):

Below code works.

For Variables to String

```
>>> a = 10
>>> b =20
>>> c = 30
>>> lst = [a,b,c]
>>> lst
[10, 20, 30]
>>> {str(item):item for item in lst}
{'10': 10, '30': 30, '20': 20}
```

For string only.

```
    >>> lst = ['a','b','c']
    >>> lst
    ['a', 'b', 'c']
    >>> {item:item for item in lst}
    {'a': 'a', 'c': 'c', 'b': 'b'}
```

Comment: Your list contains strings whereas in question list contains variables. This is not what asked.

Comment: anuragal: same concept works with variables as well.

Comment: Please read the question carefully

Comment: Thanks Anuragal updated answer as per question, hope it makes more sense now

Comment: @PavanGupta:Nope, this would return you `{'10':10, '20':20, ...}`.
But I want `{"a":10, "b":20, ...}`